# If Decoder Fails Use Other Decoder

Tags: json, swift, api

I am creating an application that communicates with a web app using Laravel as the backend. I am trying to handle form validation but running into an issue.

For example, let's say when a user logs in.

I am attempting to login using a URLRequest.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
}
task.resume()
```

I've created two Structs

```
struct LoginRequest: Decodable {
    let access_token: String
}
```

And

```
struct LoginErrors: Decodable {
    let error: String
    let message: String
}
```

Now I am decoding the json response with this

```
do {
     let login = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginRequest.self, from: data!)
} catch {
    // error
}
```

How can I attempt to decode the LoginErrors struct when the LoginRequest fails? If this is bad practice, what is the best way to parse the json that has the errors?

Here is an example of the json I need to handle.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 12345678,
    "access_token": "abc123",
    "refresh_token": "abc123"
}
```

```
// Error JSON
{
    "error": "invalid_credentials",
    "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
}
```

Comment: Ideally, errors should not be returned with HTTP 200 success. The Errors should be returned with a different HTTP code, say 403 in the current case which is access forbidden. Then you can parse the data after checking the HTTP Error codes.

Comment: You can typecast the response to HTTPURLResponse and the statusCode parameter will give you the https status code

Comment: @Deepika ah yes, This worked out great. Once I got the httpresponse I ran a check  `if 401...499 ~= httpResponse.statusCode {
                    let errors = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginErrors.self, from: data!)
                    print(errors)
                }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
do {
   let login = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginRequest.self, from: data!)
} catch {
   let error = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginErrors.self, from: data!)
}
```

despite this isn't a best practice you need to handle that from your server to change the returned status code and act accordingly

Comment: That actually doesn't work. I did try that before and xcode threw this error `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'`

I did get it to work by first checking the status code and trying to decode each struct that way.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ah, that does work. I did not include the `?` before.

Comment: the inner `try` needs another nested `do-catch` or `try?`

Comment: Ah. That makes sense.